# Export CSV by PHP for utf-8 characters

Tags: php, excel, csv, header

I need to export a .csv file with php. I used below code to do that:

```
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: application/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fn");
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
print($csv);
```

`$csv` contains some persian characters. When i opened the exported file with ms excel, wrong characters showed. When i opened file with notepad characters showed right.
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: is your original content in utf8? if you use utf8_encode on your $csv does that help?

Comment: Original content is in utf8. But i did not use any tag in php file for defining that, like [<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />]

Comment: You may want to test that. I've had problems in the past with such. At all points it should be in utf8 (ie. your database you are loading it from). Also reading this http://drupal.org/node/172996 seems it could be an inherent problem with csv files; one person suggests saving as .txt and opening the .txt as a csv in excel since .txt supports utf8 and csv only ascii

Comment: Excel is just notoriously bad at importing "weird" (in large quotes) encodings. Try its File > Import functions, not the regular double click.

Comment: try generating [utf16 instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5368288/309483)

Comment: you could [try writing xlsx instead](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it.

```
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
```

Earlier i was getting garbage characters now correct data is exported.