# charset utf-8 not working on Export as excel seet

Tags: php, utf-8

i am try to export excel sheet in in php. all is fine but German character is not working

my header is like :

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-type:application/x-msexcel; charset=utf-8");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=report.xls");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
```

in html live page it shows German character n utf8 like `ßäöü` but when i export as excel then in excel sheet it is like `ÃŸÃ¤Ã¶Ã¼` why ?

Comment: You can essentially delete all the `Content-Type`-headers except the last one (since that is the only one which gets sent to the client). Plus excel doesn't know anything about HTTP-headers, it'll just open the file. How do you create the excel-file? Also: check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5368288/855532).