# tabbed char in UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, xls

I am trying to create xls file output of my mysql table and i need UTF8 encoding of file export.php because of slovakian chars - ľ č š ť ž ý ... but when i convert it to UTF8 my script cant print \t character

```
// part of export.php

header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$sql = ("select * from zakaznici");
$db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

if (!$result = $db->query($sql))
{
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

// define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)

$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

// start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields

$finfo = $result->fetch_fields();

foreach($finfo as $val)
{
    printf("%s\t", $val->name);
}

print ("\n");
$schema_insert = "";

while ($ser = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $id = $ser['id'];
    $email = $ser['email'];
    $password = $ser['pass'];
    $schema_insert.= $id . $sep . $email . $sep . $password;
    print ("\n");
}

$schema_insert = str_replace($sep . "$", "", $schema_insert);
$schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
$schema_insert.= "\t";
print (trim($schema_insert));
print "\n";
```

\n character works fine .. only \t with UTF8 doesnt work
thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, that the UTF-8 BOM marker is missing at the start of the generated 
file. So, i would suggest adding the BOM before the content output, like so:

```
print "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
print trim($schema_insert);
print "\n";
```

Some suggest to use `mb_convert_encoding()`, see here: [php header excel and utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368150/php-header-excel-and-utf-8)