# Export (HTML) to Excel doesn't display umlaut correctly

Tags: excel, utf-8, coldfusion, xls, iso-8859-1

With Coldfusion when I export HTML as an .XLS file, characters containing an umlaut, such as (ü,ö,ä), do not display correctly. For example, they display as `Ã¼` or `Ã¢` instead of umlauts.

I tried these solutions, but no change.

```
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=windows-1252" reset="yes">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel;charset_ISO-8859-1 "/>
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel;charset_utf-8"/>
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=dt_memadr_xls.xls" charset="iso-8859-1">
```

Comment: Please show us the data you are exporting. Without more information it sounds like it is actually HTML  - *not* a binary Excel file.

Comment: @Leigh It is query and html table.

Comment: (Edit) Do the characters display correctly on screen ie without the download? If so, that suggests the problem is Excel's interpretation of the HTML. Might try some of the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368150/php-header-excel-and-utf-8

Comment: @Leigh with this <cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=windows-1252" reset="yes">
work perfeclty in IE and Firefox, But in Chrome and Opera dosent show umlauts.

Comment: @Leigh 1. Charachters have normal output on Screen with Chrome and Opera . 2. i tried meta tag and still dosent work . 3. i speak about coldfusion and this thread is for PHP. i think what you in this page meas, is  like meta tag with utf-8.

Comment: RE: *this thread is for PHP* Yes, but the issue seems to be how Excel interprets the HTML (regardless of which app generated it). In which case, the solution would likely be the same for any language.  RE: *like meta tag* Though the `<cfcontent>` is similar, it is only used by the browser. IIRC, Excel (and other Office programs) specifically use the `<meta> tag when handling HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Answer .I added this tag to head.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Not quite. Since it is an Excel issue, all you should need is `<meta>`. (Like I mentioned above, that is what Excel uses for HTML). Header information is only used by the browser. Voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: *all you should need is `<meta>`* ... meaning, the charset in the cfcontent is redundant.