# Getting Garbled Text while using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to generate an .ods document using PHP Excel.
Below is the code i am using :

```
public function init() {
        $this->objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    }

public function indexAction(){
    $iexpertsMapper = new Application_Model_IExpertsMapper(); 
    $response = $iexpertsMapper->getAllIExpertsPaymentDues();

    $this->objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("D")
                     ->setLastModifiedBy("D")
                     ->setTitle("D")
                     ->setSubject("D")
                     ->setDescription("D")
                     ->setKeywords("D")
                     ->setCategory("D");
    // Headers
    $this->objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'H')
            ->setCellValue('B1', strtotime("today"))
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'CTPL');

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (OpenDocument)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=bank.ods');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->objPHPExcel, 'OpenDocument');
    ob_end_clean();
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
}
```

Whenever i hit the code from the browser, an ods document is downloaded with gibberish text. I tried various things including adding ob_end_clean(); in my code. But nothing seems to work. Following text appears in my ODS document :  �QĿi!��K�y3�J<���Z1�0?Y�L%zV.

This is what i see when i open the document : 
[image]

Comment: `header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");` try adding this header, im not so sure. check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/5368150/4229270

Comment: Still gibberish.

Comment: Where did you get the OpenDocument writer? Can't find it bundled with the library.

Comment: It is the PHP Excel library. This is the sample code for reference: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/01simple-download-ods.php

Comment: From what I see on your screenshot, this is how a normal XLSX file looks like. ODS uses the same trick, using a Zip file. I see you are doing a Text Import tough, does that happen when you just double click?

Comment: Yes, as the ods document downloads and i double click on the icon, the above screen comes and when i enter OK, document opens up with garbled text.

Comment: Any Alternate library which i can use instead of PHPExcel?

Comment: The ob_end_clean should be suppressing anthing that's being injected into the output stream before the save file; but from the screenshot, it still looks like a blank line has been injected at the beginning of the file