# mathematical symbols like α β γ δ are not getting upload in database using php excel_reader2

Tags: phpexcelreader

ISOLDE Î± Î² Î³ Î´  Randomised, double blind, placebo controlled study of fluticasone propionate in patients with moderate to severe chronic obstructive pulmonary disease: the ISOLDE trial    GaliÃ¨ N et al Î± Î² Î³ Î´

Comment: set character encoding - `utf8_general_ci` for your desired database table column.

Comment: already did that but issue not solved

Comment: here is the reference for the similar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368150/php-header-excel-and-utf-8/25822631

Comment: exact issue is when i am uploading file using php excel reader2 special symbols like α β γ δ get converted ( Î± Î² Î³ Î´) in this format  i have not issue with è  these symbols